# ADO.NET EF - populate DataGridView when we have Foreign Key

Tags: c#, sql, foreign-keys, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am fairly new to `ORMs` and `ADO.NET EF` in particular. I'm using the `Code First` approach. I have these two tables in my `DB` :

`Material`:

```
public class Material
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(10)]
        public string Code { get; set; }


        [MaxLength(40)]
        public string Color { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(40)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(255)]
        public string Picture { get; set; }

        public long MaterialTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual MaterialType MaterialType { get; set; }

    }
```

and `MaterialType` :

```
public class MaterialType 
  { 
      [MaxLength(40)] 
      public string MatType { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<Material> Materials { get; set; }
  }
```

And I have a `DataGridView` where I populate with all the info from `Material` except `MatType` which is `Leather`, `Plastic` and stuff like that and which I have to take from the `MaterialType` table. It's the only `FK` so far so I've user `SELECT *..` before and now when it comes to it I don't know how to construct my code/query so I can populate the `DataGridView` with the info from the second table. In the `DataGridView` I have the column `MaterialTypeId` which is hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use DataTransferObjects(DTO).

```
public class MaterialDTO
{
        public string Code { get; set; }

        public string Color { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string Picture { get; set; }

        public string MatType { get; set; }
}
```

Then complete it with info:

```
List<MaterialDTO> listForGrid = context.Material.Select(e=>new MaterialDTO(){Code=e.Code, Color = e.Color, Description = e.Description, Picture = e.Picture, MatType = e.MaterialType.MatType}).ToList();
```

This example gets whole data from the DB from Table `Material`, and puts it to `List<MaterialDTO> listForGrid`. Maybe you will also want to put `Where` before the `Select`, to take only part of data from the table but not the whole table.

Then bind this data to Grid...