# EF nested tables eager loading?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, eager-loading

My table relations:

`Categories` has many `Posts` has many `PostImages`

I want to retrieve Categories>LastPost>FirstPostImage. And I tried something like following:

```
var categories = entity.Categories
                 .Where(x => x.PositionId == 2)
                 .Include(x => x.Posts.Last())
                 .Include(x => x.Posts.Last().PostImages.First())
                 .Take(5)
                 .ToList();
```

Question: Is there an elegant way to achive this? Is there commonly usage of eager loading for nested relational tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF doens't support queries on included tables, but you can use a `Select` clause for sub-queries:

```
var categories = entity.Categories
  .Where(x => x.PositionId == 2)
  .Select( x => new {
    Category = x,
    LastPost = x.Posts.Last(),
    FirstImage = x.Posts.Last().PostImages.First(),
  })
  .Take(5)
  .ToList();
```

You will end up with a `List<anonymous>` but it will get ( just ) the data you need.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use Data transfer Objects(DTO). Just create new class:

```
public class CategoriesPostPostImagesDto
{
     public Categories Category {get;set;}
     public Posts Post {get;set;}
     public PostImages PostImage {get;set;}

}
```

And then select data to it from DB.

```
List<CategoriesPostPostImagesDto> data = entity.Categories
  .Where(x => x.PositionId == 2)
  .Select( x => new CategoriesPostPostImagesDto(){
    Category = x,
    Post = x.Posts.Last(),
    PostImage = x.Posts.Last().PostImages.First(),
  })
  .Take(5)
  .ToList();
```

There is a lot of information about the DTO in the internet:

like this:
[ADO.NET EF - populate DataGridView when we have Foreign Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14960982/ado-net-ef-populate-datagridview-when-we-have-foreign-key/14961428#14961428)